# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2018-01-01' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[USP_xyz]
AS
declare 
@date varchar(100),
@conditiondate varchar(100);

SET @date = (SELECT top 1 column1 from mytable ORDER BY column1 DESC);

set @conditiondate = SUBSTRING(@date,1,10) ;
SELECT CONVERT(INT, @conditiondate) ;

print @conditiondate
return @conditiondate;
GO
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking that isn't already covered by the error message.

Comment: why do you need to convert your date to a INT?

Answer (score 0):

This is the statement that's throwing the error

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, @conditiondate)
```

If you are trying to get any parts of the Date, Like Month, Day or Year, You have built-in Functions for this in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
DAY(GETDATE()),--To Get the Date
MONTH(GETDATE()),--To get The Month
YEAR(GETDATE())--To Get the Year
```

or if you are trying to Format based on some specific format, try like this

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMMDDYYYY')
```

Comment: i am trying to parse date from  @date and return in output

Comment: So you can use the Day(Youradate)

Comment: i mean ,i want 2018-01-01 in output.

Comment: Then Cast it as Date or Format like this FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd')